# Modifying Javascript for deleting unnecessary characters while inserting a phone number

Tags: javascript, onclick, viber

I use Javascript below to call the Viber messenger chat for a specific phone number I paste into the field. How to change it that when inserting a number, unnecessary characters are removed: spaces, brackets, hyphens and only the last 10 digits of the number are left?

```
<input type="tel" id="tel" pattern=".{10}" maxlength="10" required />
<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="Viber" onClick="javascript: window.open('viber://chat?number=%2B38' + document.getElementById('tel').value, '_self');" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: `window.open` can be simplified to `open`. If you want simple redirection, use `location.href = foo`, where foo is url.

Comment: Remember `.{10}` means 10 characters, `maxlength` is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic JS string functions:

```js
(function() { // Do not allow using variables outside script
  var tel = document.getElementById("tel");
  tel.maxLength = 20; // When JS enabled, limit is more than 10
  tel.pattern = ".*"; // When JS enabled, allow everything
  tel.onchange = // After input
  tel.onkeyup = // Key is up (after character written)
  tel.onkeypress = // Character writen (for repeating)
    function () {
      var str = tel.value;
      for (var str_old = null; str !== str_old;) { // Until no changes done
        str_old = str;
        str = str // You can put here more characters or regex
          .replace("-", "") // Multiple similar characters
          .replace("–", "")
          .replace("—", "")
          .replace("/", "")
          .replace(" ", "")
          .replace("(", "")
          .replace(")", "")
          .replace("[", "")
          .replace("]", "")
          .replace("{", "")
          .replace("}", "");
      }
      tel.value = str.substr(-10); // Put it back and use last 10 characters (without '-' means except first 10 characters)
    }
})()
```

```html
<input type="tel" id="tel" maxlength="10" pattern="[^-–—/ ()[\]{}]+" required  />
<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="Viber" onClick="javascript: window.open('viber://chat?number=%2B38' + document.getElementById('tel').value, '_self');" />
```

Comment: `pattern="..."` is wrong. See edit, please. (I removed `0-9` part)

Comment: Thank you Bro. Fixed. How the code could be change to add additional parameter to onClick URL? For example if I need to get such construction when I run onClick event:

`https://example.com/entered_phone_number/my_url_postfix`

Comment: @Yuri, it is still the same: `'contant' + var + 'constant' + var`, so `'https://example.com/' + document.getElementById('tel').value + '/' + foo`, where `foo` is code of `my_url_postfix`. If is `my_url_postfix` always the same (constant), use `'https://example.com/' + document.getElementById('tel').value + '/my_url_postfix'`. The code around this (`window.open(` and `, '_self');`) is still the same.

Comment: Thank you @jiwopene. You helped me a lot! Do you know how to add validation to avoid running onClick event with non-numberic data or without any entered symbols?

Comment: @Yuri,
HTML pattern: `pattern="[0-9]+"` ••• 
JS:
`if (!document.getElementById('tel').value.length || document.getElementById('tel').value.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").length)
alert("Use one or more numbers");
else
window.open('viber://chat?number=%2B38' + document.getElementById('tel').value, '_self');` ••• JS is not too hard to learn and this is quite simple task.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Should I combine patterns `pattern="[^-–—/ ()[\]{}]+"` and `pattern="[0-9]+"` or they have to be separated?

Comment: @Yuri, you can use only one, but `[0-9]+` means only numbers, so you don't need the first.

Comment: You can replace `+` with `{10}` so it will want exactly 10 characters.

Comment: And you wrote comment `tel.maxLength = 20; // When JS enabled, limit is more than 10`. Are there any mistakes in this? There should be exactly 20?

Comment: It is here because You want to allow more than 10 characters to be in the `<input>` (you can insert other characters and in JS it is limited to 10 characters using `substr`).

Comment: Oh. I see. So if I need button to work if only 10 numbers entered (no less) pattern should be like this? `pattern="[0-9]{10}"`

Comment: Thank you @jiwopene. It helpes to prevent starting window.open when there is no any symbols or if letters entered. But if less then 10 numbers entered it start working. May be I made a mistake somewhere? `<input type="tel" id="tel" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required />`

Comment: If you click the button, it reads the value as-is, use `if (document.getElementById('tel').value.length == 10)` before `window.open` to prevent opening. If you use the variant with `alert`, use `if (document.getElementById('tel').value.length != 10 || document.getElementById('tel').value.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").length) alert("Use ten numbers"); else window.open('viber://chat?number=%2B38' + document.getElementById('tel').value, '_self');`, so it notifies the user.

Comment: When I use != 10 it prevents to start even with valid number. Input: `<input type="tel" id="tel" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required />` script: `<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="Viber" onClick="javascript: if (!document.getElementById('tel').value.length != 10 || document.getElementById('tel').value.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').length) alert('Enter correct telephone number'); else window.open('viber://chat?number=%2B38' + document.getElementById('tel').value, '_self');" />`

Comment: @Yuri, you have `!` after `if (`. Check what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you once again @jiwopene! Sorry for my being so inattentive.